# Iterate over all pairs of consecutive items in a list

Tags: python, list, iterator

Given a list

```
l = [1, 7, 3, 5]
```

I want to iterate over all pairs of consecutive list items `(1,7), (7,3), (3,5)`, i.e.

```
for i in xrange(len(l) - 1):
    x = l[i]
    y = l[i + 1]
    # do something
```

I would like to do this in a more compact way, like

```
for x, y in someiterator(l): ...
```

Is there a way to do do this using builtin Python iterators? I'm sure the `itertools` module should have a solution, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Although I acceppted sberry's answer, as I asked for a simple builtin-based solution, also consider the elegant and more performant solutions by thefourtheye and HansZauber.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Just use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> l = [1, 7, 3, 5]
>>> for first, second in zip(l, l[1:]):
...     print(first, second)
...
1 7
7 3
3 5
```

If you use Python 2 (not suggested) you might consider using the `izip` function in `itertools` for very long lists where you don't want to create a new list.

```
import itertools

for first, second in itertools.izip(l, l[1:]):
    ...
```

Comment: Meh... in Python 2, `zip()` returns a new list. Better use `itertools.izip()`.

Comment: In Python 3, `zip()` returns an iterator. Better use Python 3.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be `zip(l[:-1], l[1:])` instead `zip(l, l[1:])`?

Comment: This creates a copy of `l` (almost all of its elements) with no reason.

Comment: OK, your comment below answers that... :)

Comment: @flonk, not necessarily as zip will try to make complete groups.

Comment: @HansZauber: perhaps that is a problem, and perhaps it is not.  The OP's example input certainly is not enough to warrant worrying about such things.  If performance due to a huge dataset is a concern then I expect that to be part of the question.

Comment: There is also an elegant way by using more_itertools, leading to 
for (first, second) in windowed(l,2):

Answer (score 44):

Look at `pairwise` at itertools recipes: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

Quoting from there:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

---

**A General Version**

A general version, that yields tuples of any given positive natural size, may look like that:

```
def nwise(iterable, n=2):                                                      
    iters = tee(iterable, n)                                                     
    for i, it in enumerate(iters):                                               
        next(islice(it, i, i), None)                                               
    return izip(*iters)
```

Comment: I like this approach because it doesn't copy the input iterable. For python3, just use `zip` instead of `izip`.

Comment: How to extend this to also include (sLast, s0)? So instead of yielding n-1 pairs, return n pairs?

Comment: @normanius I think the easiest way to extend this is to just pad the end of `iterable` with a copy of the relevant values from its beginning: `nwise(chain(a, islice(b, n-1)), n)` where `a, b = tee(iterable)`

Comment: For Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise

Answer (score 14):

I would create a generic `grouper` generator, like this

```
def grouper(input_list, n = 2):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list) - (n - 1)):
        yield input_list[i:i+n]
```

**Sample run 1**

```
for first, second in grouper([1, 7, 3, 5, 6, 8], 2):
    print first, second
```

*Output*

```
1 7
7 3
3 5
5 6
6 8
```

**Sample run 1**

```
for first, second, third in grouper([1, 7, 3, 5, 6, 8], 3):
    print first, second, third
```

*Output*

```
1 7 3
7 3 5
3 5 6
5 6 8
```

Comment: You can write generator comprehension like this   

`pair_generator = ((list[i], list[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(list)-1))`

Answer (score 4):

Generalizing sberry's approach to nwise with comprehension:

```
def nwise(lst, k=2):
    return list(zip(*[lst[i:] for i in range(k)]))
```

Eg

```
nwise(list(range(10)),3)
```

> [(0, 1, 2),  (1, 2, 3),  (2, 3, 4),  (3, 4, 5),  (4, 5, 6),  (5, 6,
>   7),  (6, 7, 8),  (7, 8, 9)]

Answer (score 3):

A simple means to do this without unnecessary copying is a generator that stores the previous element.

```
def pairs(iterable):
    """Yield elements pairwise from iterable as (i0, i1), (i1, i2), ..."""
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        prev = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for item in it:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
```

Unlike index-based solutions, this works on any iterable, including those for which indexing is not supported (e.g. generator) or slow (e.g. `collections.deque`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `zip`.

```
>>> list(zip(range(5), range(2, 6)))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Just like a zipper, it creates pairs. So, to to mix your two lists, you get:

```
>>> l = [1,7,3,5]
>>> list(zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))
[(1, 7), (7, 3), (3, 5)]
```

Then iterating goes like

```
for x, y in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]):
    pass
```

Comment: You don't need to trim the end of the first one as zip will only make complete groups.  That would be different if you were using `izip_longest`, but then why would you do that.

Comment: @sberry: You are correct, but I like it better explicit, this way. It's something personal, I guess.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanted something inline but not terribly readable here's another solution that makes use of generators. I expect it's also not the best performance wise :-/

Convert list into generator with a tweak to end before the last item:

```
gen = (x for x in l[:-1])
```

Convert it into pairs:

```
[(gen.next(), x) for x in l[1:]]
```

That's all you need.

Comment: For `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]` this produces `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]` and not `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]` as requested. It also only works when the list contains an even number of items.

Comment: Oops you're right. I'm sorry, I shouldn't post crap on the internet w/o testing it. I've corrected it to work now (hopefully)  if you were interested in this form of solution anyhow.