# Split a string with list of numbers

Tags: python, list, split

I'm trying to split a string by the positions given from a list, and add the parts to a new list.  I start with:

```
seq = 'ATCGATCGATCG'
seq_new = []
seq_cut = [2, 8 , 10]
```

I would like to get:

```
seq_new = ['AT', 'CGATCG', 'AT', 'CG']
```

The list with the positions is variable in size and values.  How can I process my data like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to create indexes for [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation):

```
seq_new = [seq[start:end] for start, end in zip([None] + seq_cut, seq_cut + [None])]
```

This zips together `[None, 2, 8 , 10]` and `[2, 8, 10, None]` to create the indexes `[(None, 2), (2, 8), (8, 10), (10, None)]`.  `None` as first index defaults to zero, `None` as the second index defaults to the size of the sequence being sliced.

Comment: Darn it - was just going to copy/paste from my editor almost exactly the same :p

Comment: For added symmetry you can use `None` on the first one (like I just did! :P)

Comment: This can be made even more elegant by using a modified version of the "pairwise" recipe (left as exercise to the reader) described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21303303/4621513)! The resulting expression would be `[seq[start:end] for start, end in pairwise(seq_cut)]`

Comment: @mkrieger1:  An implementation of `pairwise` can be found in the recipe's section of the `itertools` docs.  I don't think it's worth it here.  The code is roughly the same:  `seq_new = [seq[start:end] for start, end in pairwise([None] + seq_cut + [None])]`

Comment: Yes, I also think it's not worth it unless it's going to be used more than only a few times. And I meant to append `None` in the front and back inside a modified version of `pairwise`, to hide that little detail from the user.

Answer (score 4):

Use slicing:

```
seq = "ATCGATCGATCG"
seq_new = []
seq_cut = [2, 8, 10]

last = 0
for idx in seq_cut:
    seq_new.append(seq[last:idx])
    last = idx
seq_new.append(seq[last:])
```

Comment: Python slicing syntax can be daunting to people unfamiliar with it, but it's super powerful (+1) https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html