# How to i extract a substring from a string in Python and store it in a list?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a string `"ababa"` . I want to extract all the substring of length say, 2, and store it in a list like `['ab' , 'ba' , 'ab', 'ba' ]`.

Here is what i have already tried, (I beforehand know that size of string is N):

```
str = input()
for k in range (N- 2 +1)
      sub[k] = str[k:k+2]
```

But this line of code gives error as the last line is illegal assignment. ( I am new to Python and have tried simply drawing a correlation with C++ )

Comment: Do you have tried anything to solve your problem so far?

Comment: i tried slicing and directly storing it in list, like this a[i]=str[beg:end]... But this gives run time error. I am very new to Python.. Infact in the process of learning.. I have previous experience with C++, and what i tried was a correlation

Comment: @SrivatsaSinha if you show your attempt - others can advise you on how to fix it - that shows an effort on your part and will also help you learn

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This is likely to get closed as it's basically a request for code, without showing what you've already tried.  I recommend you edit in what you've tried.  You might also like to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303224/iterate-over-all-pairs-of-consecutive-items-from-a-given-list - you can apply the answers there to a string .  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`string[a:b]` is what you're looking for. It gives you the characters between `a` and `b` (including a). Knowing that, you have to search for all of the n-substrings starting with 0 and ending with `len(your_string) - n + 1` To aim for the elegant and Pythonic solution, read something about:

> List Comprehensions

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Good luck!