# Trying to search 2 characters at a time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm just getting back into python, and I'm trying to search over two characters at a time through a string, and replace them with something else. Such as searching through the string "aah" for the string "aa" and replacing it with something else, such as "xx" but when I try to run it, it says type must be a string, not int. This is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
test = input("enter words to encrypt\n")
#print(test)

#change a letter
def changea(test):
    #print(test)
    outp = ""
    for i in test:
        if i & i+1  == "aa":
            outp += "x"
        else:
            outp += i

    print(outp)
changea(test)
```

Comment: the logical and operator in Python is the keyword `and`. `&` is the _bitwise_ and operator.

Comment: To address your main problem, `i+1` fails because `i` is a string from the string `test`, and `1` is an integer. You probably meant to _index_ the string with the integer, rather than directly attempt to add the integer and string.

Comment: Related - [Iterate over all pairs of consecutive items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21303224/2823755) - This accepted answer would work for a string also.

Comment: you can use if test.count("a") == 2:  # do something

Comment: You may find [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) useful

Comment: @ChristianDean I changed that line to    if test[i] and test[i+1] == "aa":  but I still get an error that says string indices must be integers. How would I go about changing this?

Comment: `if test[i] and test[i+1] == "aa"` checks whether `test[i+1] == "aa"` **and** `test[i]`. The latter condition is always true for printable characters. You need `if test[i]=="aa" and test[i+1] == "aa"`. Also, the loop header must be changed, too.

Comment: Is `i` not a string @DyZ? How would you index a string `test` with a string `i`?

Comment: @ChristianDean I posted an unfinished comment. Yes, that's another problem with the OP's code.

Comment: @DyZ So how would I change I so that it would work?

Comment: Well, you have two answers down there, choose what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should use `replace` or `re.sub`. But if you are committed to using a loop, here's what you may try:

```
def changea(test):
    pairs = zip(test, test[1:] + "$")
    out = ""
    for x, y in pairs:
        if x == "a" and y == "a":
            out += "x"
            next(pairs) # Skip the next iteration
        else:
            out += x
    return out

changea("Maary haad aa little laamb")
#'Mxry hxd x little lxmb'
```

Comment: So how would you change this to not exclude the last character? Would that be with using the replace function?

Comment: Smart move; but I fixed it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator does a `bitwise and` on two integers. Your for-loop loops over a string so the loop variable `i` takes successive characters of the string as its values. Hence the error: you are applying the `&` operator on a character. In addition, `i+1` is meaningless: it tries to apply the `+` operator to a character and an integer - python will complain that you cannot concatenate a character and an integer.

The `i & i+1` expression was meant to give you two adjacent characters but it's wrong.

There are a few ways to proceed: one is to loop over the string using indices (which I guess is what you were trying to do, since you named the for-loop variable `i`, the traditional name for a loop index).

```
for i in range(len(test)):
```

will make `i` an integer ranging from `0` to `len(test)-1`. Then you need to slice off two characters of the string starting at position `i`:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
     if test[i:i+2] == "aa":
         outp += "x"
     else:
         outp += test[i]
```

You have to remember that the index over a string goes from `0` to `len(string) - 1` and you also have to remember that the slice `test[i:j]` is the piece of the string between indices `i` and `j-1` (*NOT* `j`).

This is not particularly idiomatic python, but I hope it's understandable.