# R iterate over consecutive pairs in a list

Tags: r, list

suppose I have the following vector:

`v1 = c(1,2,3,4)`

I need to iterate over this vector in a pairwise fashion, like `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)`. For python, there is a solution to this problem here: [Iterate over all pairs of consecutive items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303224/iterate-over-all-pairs-of-consecutive-items-in-a-list). Can a similar solution be achieved in R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can remove the `first` and `last` elements and concatenate in `Map`

```
Map(c,  v1[-length(v1)], v1[-1])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 3 4
```

---

Or `rbind` and use `asplit`

```
asplit(rbind(v1[-length(v1)], v1[-1]), 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just `cbind` the shifted vector.

```
cbind(v1[-length(v1)], v1[-1])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    3    4
```

R is vectorized, no need for iteration.

Answer (score 3):

These solutions all easily generalize to windows of greater than 2 by replacing 2 with some other number.

**1) rollapply** Replace `toString` with whatever function you want to use.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(v1, 2, toString)
## [1] "1, 2" "2, 3" "3, 4"
```

**1a)** or create a 2 column matrix and then iterate over that in a second step:

```
library(zoo)
m <- rollapply(v1, 2, c)
apply(m, 1, toString)
## [1] "1, 2" "2, 3" "3, 4"
```

**2) embed**  or use `embed`.  This does not use any packages.

```
e <- embed(v1, 2)[, 2:1]
apply(e, 1, toString)
## [1] "1, 2" "2, 3" "3, 4"
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `embed` + `asplit`

```
> asplit(embed(v1,2)[,2:1],1)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 4
```