# How to iterate over all consecutive subarrays of an arbitrary fixed size in a list?

Tags: python, list

problem:

```
listt= [2,0,5,4,2]
```

`listt` has 4 lists of x=2

```
[2,0],[0,5],[5,4],[4,2]
```

`listt` has 3 lists of x=3

```
[2,0,5],[0,5,4],[5,4,2]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over all pairs of consecutive items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303224/iterate-over-all-pairs-of-consecutive-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

You can use list-comprehension and take the subsequent slices

```py
>>> listt= [2,0,5,4,2]
>>> n=2
>>> [listt[i:i+n] for i in range(len(listt)-n+1)]
[[2, 0], [0, 5], [5, 4], [4, 2]]  # n=2
>>> n=3
>>> [listt[i:i+n] for i in range(len(listt)-n+1)]
[[2, 0, 5], [0, 5, 4], [5, 4, 2]]  # n=3
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21303303/2099608) you can use:

```
from itertools import tee

def nwise(iterable, n=2):                                                      
    iters = tee(iterable, n)                                                     
    for i, it in enumerate(iters):                                               
        next(islice(it, i, i), None)                                               
    return izip(*iters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested comprehension:

```
gen = (listt[i:i + n] for n in range(2, len(listt + 1)) for i in range(len(listt) - n + 1))
```

You can use the resulting generator, for example by printing it:

```
for sub in gen:
    print(sub)
```

You may want to start `n` at 1 rather than 2, since those are valid sublists too.