# Python Threading: Each thread with different starting

Tags: python, multithreading

so I have a JSON user database, I want to check if user has a valid id or not, if not then remove it from database. I am using threads for this but each thread will start from the starting of database, I don't want that.

Example: if thread A starts from 10 then thread B will start from 20. Also when thread A ends, I want it to start from 30 instead of 20.

I am a beginner so detailed guide & explanation would be great!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can u show what u have tried?

Comment: Hi, here is the [sample of current code](https://pastebin.com/NSTxrDea)

Comment: the link is full of animations, spots & co... could you please just edit your question with your code?

Comment: I dont really know why cant u use a single thread to for all of it. or why do u need to usse threads for that from the code u posted but [Threading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-python-set-2-synchronization/) should help as reference, from what I understand, you can use `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` with the help of `lock = threading.Lock()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example :

```py
import threading
import time
import typing

MAX_NUMBER = 57  # assumed to be inclusive
JOB_SIZE = 10

indexes = tuple(
    tuple(range(0, MAX_NUMBER + 1, JOB_SIZE)) + (MAX_NUMBER + 1,)
)
jobs_spans = tuple(zip(indexes, indexes[1:]))  # cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/21303286/11384184

print(jobs_spans)
# ((0, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 58))

jobs_left = list(jobs_spans)  # is thread-safe thanks to the GIL


def process_user(user_id: int) -> None:
    sleep_duration = ((user_id // JOB_SIZE) % 3) * 0.4 + 0.1  # just to add some variance to each job
    time.sleep(sleep_duration)


def process_users() -> typing.NoReturn:
    while True:
        try:
            job = jobs_left.pop()
        except IndexError:
            break  # no job left
        else:
            print(f"{threading.current_thread().name!r} processing users from {job[0]} to {job[1]} (exclusive) ...")
            for user_id in range(job[0], job[1]):
                process_user(user_id)
                print(f"user {user_id} processed")
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name!r} finished")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=process_users)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=process_users)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

I started by computing the spans that the jobs will cover, using only the number of users and the size of each job.
I use it to define a queue of jobs left. It is actually a list that the threads will `pop` onto.
I have two different functions :

- one to process a user given its id, which has nothing to do with threading, i could use it the exact same way in a completely sequential program
- one to handle the threading. It is the `target` of the threads, which means which code will get executed by each threads once it is `started`ed. It is an infinite loop, which try to get a new job until there is no more.

I `join` each thread to wait for its completion, before the script exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have time to understand [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69344483/17007489) code, then you can use this. Its easy & small.

[Original Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/17007489)

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4)

# Execute function in their own Threads
results = pool.map(func, arg)

# Close the pool and wait for the work to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

`func` is your function that you want to execute.
`arg` is your function arg

Example:

```js
names = ["John", "David", "Bob"]

def printNames(name):
  print(name)

results = pool.map(printNames, names)
```

It will print all names from `names` list using `printNames` function.
function arg - `names`

**Links**

- Multiprocessing ([python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiprocessing-python-set-1/))
- Functions ([w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp))